# Composition issues in entity framework 4: The entity is currently read-only

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity, composition

Using WCF RIA Services and entity framework 4.

I have 3 DTOs:  School, State, District.
The state DTO has a District property with composition.  And the School DTO has a State property with composition and a District association.

The idea, is that when we create/update a school, we also allow the user to enter the state and district (which can be existing or new).

When creating a new state and district, everything works fine.  But when I create just a new district inside of an existing state, I get the following error: "This entity is currently read-only. One of the following conditions exist: a custom method has been invoked, a submit operation is in progress, or edit operations are not supported for the entity Type"

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm getting the same error except it only occurs very infrequently and it is difficult to reproduce.  I wish I could figure out a good way to debug this...

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this one today and determined that my bug was caused by the 2nd issue described in the error message: "a submit operation is in progress."

Here is my **incorrect** code:

```
dim c as new Car()
myContext.Cars.add(c)
myContext.SubmitChanges()
c.Color = "Red"
```

Note that I incorrectly changed the entity after the SubmitChanges call.  Although SubmitChanges occurs before I modify my entity, SubmitChanges occurs asynchronously, so there is no guarantee that the changes will be submitted before I modify the entity.

Here is the corrected code:

```
dim c as new Car()
myContext.Cars.add(c)
c.Color = "Red"
myContext.SubmitChanges()
```